# VS Code Regex search: find a term inside loop/function/etc?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code's Search panel, let's say I want to find `foo` only if it's in a while loop. So in the example below, I'd only want to find `foo = baz`. How would I go about composing this search term?

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

numbers.forEach((number) => {
    foo = 'bar';
});

let count = 0;
while (count < numbers.length) {
  count++;
  foo = 'baz';
}

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  foo = 'qux';
}
```

I've attempted a few different regexes, but the closest I've gotten is `while.*\n*.*foo`, which will find it only if it's on the very next line. With `count++` there, it doesn't find it.

Comment: while(.|\n)*?foo or perhaps while(.|\r\n)*?foo depending on your line terminators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a capturing group with a lazy quantifier.

The first capturing group, `()`, will allow replacing only the foo while keeping the rest with $1.

The lazy quantifier, `*?`, means match zero on more times but as few times as possible. That makes it stop at foo instead of matching from the first while to the last foo.

The second capturing group could technically be non capturing `(?:.|\n)` but in this case it doesn't really matter, and it makes the expression compacter, leaving it as capturing group.

```
Search: (while(.|\n)*?)foo
Replace: $1bar
```

https://regex101.com/r/uabB8z/1

It will make this

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

while (count < numbers.length) {
  count++;
  foo = 'baz';
}

numbers.forEach((number) => {
    foo = 'bar';
});

let count = 0;
while (count < numbers.length) {
  count++;
  foo = 'baz';
}

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  foo = 'qux';
}

while (count < numbers.length) {foo = 'baz';  count++;}

while (count < numbers.length) {
  foo = 'baz';  count++;
}
```

Into this

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

while (count < numbers.length) {
  count++;
  bar = 'baz';
}

numbers.forEach((number) => {
    foo = 'bar';
});

let count = 0;
while (count < numbers.length) {
  count++;
  bar = 'baz';
}

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  foo = 'qux';
}

while (count < numbers.length) {bar = 'baz';  count++;}

while (count < numbers.length) {
  bar = 'baz';  count++;
}
```

Comment: I agree that regex isn't the best for parsing language syntax; however your example works and was just what I was looking for. Thanks. It also illustrates your point about it being a complicated matter. I wish it was as simple as `while*foo` or somesuch, but your answer shows why it's not.

Comment: I managed to simply the expression by using a lazy quantifier.  @rotarydial.